# Cómo hacer una consulta a una tabla compuesta su llave primaria con dos llaves foráneas en php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, phpmyadmin

Amigos por favor necesito saber ¿Cómo realizar una consulta a la tabla 'respuestas' la cual su llave primaria esta compuesta por 2 llaves foráneas? 
Necesito un ejemplo cual es la sintaxis.  Supongamos  ¿cual es la respuesta del alumno con id 5 en la pregunta con id 1?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `SELECT r.respuesta FROM respuestas r INNER JOIN alumno a ON r.id_alumno=a.id_alumno INNER JOIN preguntas p ON r.id_pregunta=p.id_pregunta WHERE a.id_alumno=5`   ... las letras que he usado son simplemente *alias*  de cada tabla.

Comment: Como te indica @A.Cedano aún que si solo quieres el registro no necesitas los JOIN solo haz los WHERE con los id, ejemplo: `SELECT * FROM respuestas WHERE id_alumno=5 AND id_pregunta=1`

Comment: Gracias amigos realmente si me funcionaron las dos consultas.